# How to map two objects (sources) to one destination on different properties

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've been using `EF Core (2.2)` and `Automapper`. I have some objects: two entities (Partner, PartnerStatus) and the integration model (IntegrationPartnerModel).
I need to map two objects (Partner, IntegrationPartnerModel) to one (PartnerStatus) on different properties.

Below is a definition of each of them:

```
public class Partner {
   public int PartnerId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Comment { get; set; }

   // Relation Partner and PartnerStatus
   public int PartnerStatusId { get; set; }

   // Navigation property to PartnerStatus
   public PartnerStatus PartnerStatus { get; set; }

   // Relation IntegrationPartnerModel and PartnerStatus
   public string PartnerStatusCode { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerStatus {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // Status code from integration service
   public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class IntegrationPartnerModel {
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // relation to PartnerStatus entity (Code property)
   public string PartnerStatusCode { get; set; }

   // Navigation property to PartnerStatus entity
   public PartnerStatus PartnerStatus { get; set; }

   // etc
}
```

I've made two Automapper's profiles:

```
public class PartnerStatusProfile : Profile {
   public PartnerStatusProfile()
   {
      CreateMap<PartnerStatus, Partner>()
         .ForMember(p => p.PartnerStatusId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
         .ReverseMap();

      CreateMap<PartnerStatus, IntegrationModel>()
         .ForMember(p => p.PartnerStatusCode, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Code))
         .ReverseMap();
   }
}

public class PartnerProfile : Profile
{
   public PartnerProfile() {

      CreateMap<IntegrationPartnerModel, Partner>()
         .IncludeMembers(integration => integration.PartnerStatus)
         .ForMember(p => p.PartnerStatusCode, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.PartnerStatusCode))
   }
}
```

Mapping Partner and PartnerStatus (PartnerStatusId is relation) is successfull.

But mapping of IntegrationPartnerModel and Partner (PartnerStatusCode is relation) is failed.

```
var integrationPartnerModel = new IntegrationPartnerModel {
    PartnerStatusCode = "ABC"
    //...
};

var newPartner = _mapper.Map<IntegrationPartnerModel, Partner>(integrationPartnerModel);
```

Property newPartner.PartnerStatusCode = "" (default) and newPartner.PartnerStatus is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the profiles to the mapper configuration var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
   {
    cfg.AddProfile<PartnerProfile>();
    cfg.AddProfile<PartnerStatusProfile>();
   }); ?

Comment: Indeed you also don't need the IncludeMemeber and ForMember, you can just say CreateMap<IntegrationPartnerModel,Partner>();. It will automatically map the relevant objects